Trouble capturing network traffic on Ubuntu
I'm working on a project that uses CICFlowMeter. It is a tool that captures realtime net flows and can export them in a csv format. When using the program I can use the offline mode perfectly where it converts pcap to csv but when I try to use the realtime mode where it reads raw newtork traffic I begin to run into a problem. The program reads all network adapters as 'null'.
I have ran:
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
which I thought would install the necessary dependencies but this problem still occurs. Any advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Advice is to talk to the people that make the tool. Your question lacks any details not even a version of Ubuntu is mentioned.
